# Django Admin Page is looking very Ugly(without CSS I think)

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2

Recently I hosted my django website on EC2 ubuntu Instance with nginx server on AWS. When I open my admin page of this website IT is looking very ugly and there is not css but on local server 127.0.0.0:8000 it works fine.
[image: Django Admin Page]

I also inspect on browser console, It is giving this error:

```
GEThttp://jassem.in/static/admin/css/dashboard.css
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 51ms]

The resource from “http://jassem.in/static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
admin
The resource from “http://jassem.in/static/admin/css/base.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
admin
The resource from “http://jassem.in/static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
admin
The resource from “http://jassem.in/static/admin/css/responsive.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
admin
The resource from “http://jassem.in/static/admin/css/dashboard.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
admin
```

How can I get back my previous django admin page. FYI I am a newbie on web technology and Django

Comment: You need `collectstatic` files in porduction enviroment

Comment: How can i do that? Any Idea

Answer (score 1):

if the problem apply on all the pages of your project try collectstatic,
Django provides a command to collect static files from all applications
into a single location. This simplifies the setup for serving static files in production.

Open the shell and run the following command:

python manage.py collectstatic

You will see this output:
165 static files copied to '/yourproject/static'.
Files located under the static/ directory of each application present in the
INSTALLED_APPS setting have been copied to the global /yourproject/static/ project
directory.

then, edit the config/nginx.conf file and add:

```
location /static/ {alias /home/projects/yourproject/static/;}
location /media/ {alias /home/projects/yourproject/media/;}
```

after the lines:

```
location / {
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass yourproject;
    }
```

replace the /home/projects/yourproject/ path with the absolute path
to your project directory

Answer (score 1):

This was my first deployment and I tried many things. Finally, this is what worked for me:

1. Running `python manage.py collectstatic`
2. Finding the `nginx.conf` file and within the `server{}` block, adding: `location /static/ {alias /home/projects/yourproject/static/;}` then runinng `sudo service nginx restart` from the bash terminal
3. In my `settings.py` file adding: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` and `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the collectstatic command:

1. SSH into your EC2 instance
2. Run `python manage.py collectstatic`

Assuming you have set up your static files correctly, it should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

if it does not work, try this then

```
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
```

Answer (score -1):

just turn on your DEBUG mode in the setting.py file and it will work just fine.

```
DEBUG = True
```

Comment: Never deploy a site into production with DEBUG turned on. See [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug)

Comment: you are right, i forgot he was in production mode. It just that i had the same problem and i solved it by turning on the debug mode but i was still in devellopement mode.